# Multiple Versions of anaconda(v4.0.0 and v4.6.8)

Tags: python, anaconda

Hey Can I have multiple versions of conda. I have `conda 4.6.8` and I need `conda 4.0.0` for GraphLab. I tried `conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0` but it throughs me an error that i don't have this version install. and when I try with conda `create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.6.8` it shows GraphLab doesnot support the version. The solution I need is I can install both `V4.0.0` and `V4.6.8` in two different folders. But the problem is when try to call by command line it will call the one that i installed later. Is there Any solution that I can customise the command (Ex: `jupyter notebook version=4.0.0` to run jupyter notebook of `V4.0.0 jupyter notebook version=4.6.8` to run jupyter notebook of `V4.6.8` ?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the issue. When I execute `conda create -n gl-env python=2.7 anaconda=4.0.0` I don't receive any error. What's the exact error message that you are seeing?

Comment: I have conda 4.6.8 and i used to it. but the GraphLab doesn't support V4.6.8. So is there any possiblity of having both V4.0.0 and V4.6.8 at the same machine and can able to access both of them.

Comment: Yes, [conda environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#) allow this.